# Getting Error While Parsing Feature To The lineEdit In Python

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins, qgis-2, pyqt4

am getting error while parsing a selected feature to the lineEdit like, **QLineEdit.setText(QString): argument 1 has unexpected type 'long'**

```
layer = self.iface.activeLayer()
    h = layer.selectedFeatures()
    for f in h:
        g =  f['ID']
    self.dlg.lineEdit.setText(g)
```

Answer (score 1):

`self.dlg.lineEdit.setText(str(g))` is also not working but i got the solution

```
self.dlg.lineEdit.setText('{}'.format(g))
```

Answer (score 0):

At first glance, the problem seems obvious: `f['ID']` is not a string, it is a number of the long type, which is not accepted by the function.

Simply converting it by using `self.dlg.lineEdit.setText(str(g))` should be enough.